# VBA vs. VSTO vs. Office.js vs. MS Graph vs. MS Flow

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-js, office-2016

I have Outlook 2016 using Hosted Exchange. Here's what I need to be able to do:

- Add Outlook tasks automatically when adding a contact via a custom form.
- Send a premade .doc, .html, or .mshtml file via email to a set of contacts.
- Keep track of who has received what premade email

I have some JS experience, but I'm not afraid of getting into .NET or VBA. I'm leaning towards VSTOs because, from what I've read, Office.js doesn't seem to allow for much interoperability between, say, Word and Outlook.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, I would step outside of Outlook all together and use the[Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/). Using Graph you could wire up a [Webhook](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks) so you can capture when a new [Contact](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contact) is added and then [send an email](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send) with a [file attachment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_post_attachments). You could then use [Extended Properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview) to tag each Contact with the document/email they received.

I would also suggest taking a look at [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/).  For workflow scenarios like this, it may be a better fit.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick answer! I checked out both Graph and Flow, and it looks like they don't support Outlook 2016 with hosted exchange. Please correct me I'm wrong and just misunderstanding something.

Comment: Outlook isn't really applicable, Graph operates against Exchange itself. Both Exchange Online and O365 are supported. Support for hybrid environments (mixed on-prem and O365) is in Preview - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support